# Defining a list of complex Type in dhall

Tags: dhall

I have several types defined and two are organized into list (field and option). Functions are defined to help define entries (addfield and addoption). I'm able to define fields and works as expected; however, for options I get an error when the list has more than one element.

Here is the full dhall file:

```
let FTypes = < U8 | U16 | U32 | F32 | BITS >

let Translate = List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Text }

let Bits = < Bit0 | Bit1 | Bit2 | Bit3 | Bit4 | Bit5 | Bit6 | Bit7 >

let bits2Natural
    : Bits → Natural
    = λ(b : Bits) →
        merge
          { Bit0 = 0
          , Bit1 = 1
          , Bit2 = 2
          , Bit3 = 3
          , Bit4 = 4
          , Bit5 = 5
          , Bit6 = 6
          , Bit7 = 7
          }
          b

let Field =
      let TypeBits = { bit : Natural, width : Natural }
      in  { Type =
              { startbyte : Natural
              , type : FTypes
              , translate : Optional Translate
              , typebits : Optional TypeBits
              }
          , default = { translate = None Translate, typebits = None TypeBits }
          }

let FieldList = List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Field.Type }

let Option = { dlc : Natural, fields : FieldList, telemjson : Optional Text }

let OptionList = List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : Option }

let addfield = λ(n : Text) → λ(f : Field.Type) → { mapKey = n, mapValue = f }

let addoption = λ(k : Text) → λ(v : Option) → { mapKey = k, mapValue = v }

let testoption : OptionList =
    [ addoption "0"
        { dlc = 4
        , fields =
            [ addfield "field0" Field::{startbyte = 1, type = FTypes.U16 }
            , addfield "field1" Field::{startbyte = 3, type = FTypes.U8 }
            ]
        , telemjson = Some 
            (  "{\"sensor1\":{"
            ++ "\"time\":\"@(timestamp)\","
            ++ "\"id\":\"@(option)\","
            ++ "\"temp\":@(field0.value),"
            ++ "\"unit\":\"@(field1.value)\""
            ++ "}}"
            )
        }
    , addoption "1"
        { dlc = 2
        , fields = [ addfield "field0" Field::{startbyte = 1, type FTypes.U8 } ]
        , telemjson = Some
            ("{\"sensor2\":{\"value\":@(field1.value)}}")
        }
    ]
    
in testoption
```

And here is the error output:

```
Error: Invalid input

trial2.dhall:60:9:
   |
60 |         { dlc = 2
   |         ^
unexpected '{'
expecting ',', ->, :, ], or whitespace
```

If I remove the second option (lines 59-64), it will work?

What am I doing wrong? How can I define multiple `Option` for an `OptionList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse error could use improvement, but there is a typo in the record starting on line 60 due to a missing `=` sign here:

```
        , fields = [ addfield "field0" Field::{startbyte = 1, type FTypes.U8 } ]
                                                                  ↑
```

It should be:

```
        , fields = [ addfield "field0" Field::{startbyte = 1, type = FTypes.U8 } ]
```

… and if you make that change then the file successfully parses and type-checks.